# When using multiple WHEN MATCHED statements, do they all execute, or does only one get executed?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, merge

If I have multiple WHEN MATCHED statements in a MERGE statement, do they all execute if they're true?

My example:

```
DECLARE @X bit = NULL;

--skipping the MERGE statement, straight to WHEN MATCHED

WHEN MATCHED AND A = 1
    @X = 0;
WHEN MATCHED AND B = 1
    @X = 1;
```

What is the state of X in each of the 4 possibilities?

```
A|B|X
0|0|?
0|1|?
1|0|?
1|1|?
```

Basically, I'm curious if there's an implicit BREAK after each WHEN MATCHED clause.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To answer your question, yes, it will only run a single match and then break.  However, if you'd like to have logic to allow for conditional matching in the update, the `CASE` statement is rather useful for this.

Something like this as an example:

```
MERGE INTO YourTable
USING (VALUES (1, 1, NULL), (0, 0, NULL), (0, 1, NULL), (1, 0, NULL))
       T2 (a2,b2,c2)
ON a = a2 AND b = b2
WHEN MATCHED  THEN
    UPDATE SET c = 
      CASE 
        WHEN a = 1 THEN 0
        WHEN b = 1 THEN 1
        ELSE NULL
      END        
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (a, b) VALUES (a2, b2);

SELECT * FROM YourTable ORDER BY a,b;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1f31e/1)

---

And the results:

```
A   B   C
--------------
0   0   (null)
0   1   1
1   0   0
1   1   0
```

Comment: Never heard of SQLFiddle, that's damn useful.  Thanks for the comprehensive answer.  My problem ended up being elsewhere in the sproc, but this answers my original question, so I'll mark it.  Thanks!

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 -- np, and I would agree, Fiddle is wonderful.  Best regards.

Comment: The problem with this is that you have to repeat the case statement for each field you want to change.

Answer (score 25):

I found in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx):

> WHEN MATCHED THEN
>
> Specifies that all rows of target_table that match the rows returned by  ON , and satisfy any additional search condition, are either updated or deleted according to the  clause.
>
> The MERGE statement can have at most two WHEN MATCHED clauses. If two clauses are specified, then the first clause must be accompanied by an AND  clause. For any given row, the second WHEN MATCHED clause is only applied if the first is not. If there are two WHEN MATCHED clauses, then one must specify an UPDATE action and one must specify a DELETE action. If UPDATE is specified in the  clause, and more than one row of matches a row in target_table based on , SQL Server returns an error. The MERGE statement cannot update the same row more than once, or update and delete the same row.

So it looks like only one of the statements are executed, and they require a DELETE in one and an UPDATE in the other.

Comment: This is useful to know about the maximum of 2; however, it is no longer the case (if it truly was) for it to require a DELETE statement. I'm not sure why they would say that; such an action would be inappropriate in very many circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

well, the answer is, do you really want to because if you do you would change a set based update to a row by agonising slow row update as in a set of rows you really would not know what columns changed on a record by record basis.

the question, therefore, is do you want to get performance? if so, make sure you have indexes that covering the

```
WHEN MATCHED TARGET.FIELD1 = SOURCE:FIELD1 AND TARGET.FIELD2 = SOURCE:FIELD2 ...
```

if not you are going to have to cursor over your updates after the merge using an `INSTEAD OF` trigger...

Not good for speed, however, can work if you need to record who did what...

Happy Coding

Walter